# long long division wrong

Tags: c++, long-integer, division, integer-overflow

I am working in a project and in a certain time I have this problem. I have two very large numbers and I want to divide them and get an integer/long long integer. This is what's happening:

Code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    long long n,m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    cout << n/m << endl;
}
```

The inputs can be numbers until 100,000,000,000,000,000 so the division is performing wrong.

Output

```
#1 n: 76543210987654321 m: 7654321
#2 76543210987654321/7654321 = 1410312449
```

The right answer is 10,000,000,130 so I am wondering what is happening...

Comment: It's not the division that is failing - your 64 bit `long long`s are simply not big enough to hold the values that you are entering. You'll  need to use a suitable big integer library.

Comment: How are you compiling that exactly? [I get a correct result.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d3bb181471a4a35)

Comment: @PaulR 64 bit `long long` should be enough to hold the value `76543210987654321`. If it's 32 bits, then it won't.

Comment: I also get the correct result. Are you sure you are entering the numbers correctly? Also, is your `long long` 64 bits?

Comment: Maybe use int64_t instead of long long

Comment: My compiler is g++ in windows 7 if it helps

Comment: Post more details about your compiler.

Comment: I am using Dev C++ 4.9.9.2 as editor

Comment: @MicroVirus: I was referring to the requirement to be able to work with values up to "100,000,000,000,000,000".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct result is neither `1410312449` nor `10000000130`. It is equal to `10000000129`

At least it is what the GCC shows at www.ideone.com. You can try it yourself.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    long long n = 76543210987654321;
    long long m = 7654321;

    std::cout << n / m << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It seems that you place the result of the operation in an object of type `int`. Consider the following code

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    long long n = 76543210987654321;
    long long m = 7654321;
    int x;

    x = n / m;

    std::cout << n / m << std::endl;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
10000000129
1410065537
```

Comment: The problem is that I need cin, not assing it directly

Comment: Can the problem lie inside `cin` -- can it handle `long long` input?

Comment: @Jongware The operator is overloaded for type long long. So I do not think that there is some problem with cin.

Comment: `nt main()`? Did you mean `int main()`?

Comment: I just found the answer :) It was that thing about the integer you said! Thank you all for helping!

Answer (score 2):

It seems, that the result of division is truncated to 32-bit value (`int`).
Try to use explicit cast to `long long` via `static_cast`.
Also, it is interesting to know result of `sizeof(long long)` on your compiler.